# max sum of data of allchildren and the node itself in tree

Tags: java, tree

This is the code I wrote, but it kept giving wrong ans in this test case:
(Input format: Elements in level order form separated by space (as per done in class). Order is -
Root_data, n (No_Of_Child_Of_Root), n children, and so on for every element)

```
1 3 20 30 40 1 90 2 50 6 1 100 1 150 17 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 85 86 87 88 89 92 93 94 95 96 1 80 1 83 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

ie  1:20,30,40
20:90   
30:50,6
40 100
90:150
50:17terms
6:80
100:83
```

```
class sol{
    int add;
    TreeNode<Integer> node;
    sol(int a, TreeNode<Integer> b){ add=a; node=b;}
}
public class Solution {

/*  TreeNode structure 
 * 
 * class TreeNode<T> {
        T data;
        ArrayList<TreeNode<T>> children;

        TreeNode(T data){
            this.data = data;
            children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>();
        }
    }*/


    public static TreeNode<Integer> maxSumNode(TreeNode<Integer> root){
        // Write your code here
        sol ans= sum(root);
        return ans.node;
    }

    public static sol sum(TreeNode<Integer> root){
        if(root==null) return new sol(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null);

        int add=root.data;
        for(int i=0; i<root.children.size(); i++) add+=root.children.get(i).data;
        sol ans= new sol(add, root);

        for(int i=0; i<root.children.size(); i++){
            sol temp=sum(root.children.get(i));
            if(temp.add>add) ans=temp;
        }
        return ans;
    }       
}
```

I then changed my function very slightly and it gave the right ans ie I changed the last test condition to this.

```
if(temp.add>ans.add) ans=temp;
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ans` (and thus, `ans.add`) is changing over iterations to match the biggest `sum` that has been found.

`if (temp.add > ans.add) {
     ans = temp;
}`

`add`, however, **keeps only the sum of `root`**, which has been calculated **only once**, on the first function call and is **not updated later**, in second loop.

To sum up, what you want to do is to compare consecutive values of `temp.add` to the biggest sum found to that moment (and this is `ans.add`), not to the value of sum in `root` which is stored in `add`.